# Where can I get a complete list of variables that PHP automatically makes available to my script by looking at the output of the phpinfo() function?

Tags: superglobals, php, server-variables, predefined-variables

I'm using **PHP 7.2.3** on my machine that runs on **Windows 10**.

I've installed **PHP** using latest version of **XAMPP**.

I come across following text from [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.useful.php) :

> **$_SERVER** is just one variable that PHP automatically makes available
> to you. A list can be seen in the Reserved Variables section of the
> manual or you can get a complete list of them by looking at the output
> of the phpinfo() function.

In the above text from PHP manual it has been clearly said that I can see the complete list of such variables which PHP automatically makes available to my script.

When I observed the output of `phpinfo();` I could only see the entire array of `$_SERVER[]` superglobal variable. I couldn't see any other such predefined superglobal variables in the output of `phpinfo();`

Can I say this is a mistake in PHP manual?

Or can I say the manual is saying the thing rightly but I'm not able to get it and see the other predefined superglobal variables?

Please someone help me out in this regard.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) which does exactly what you want.

There are even more of them:

1. [get_defined_constants](http://php.net/get_defined_constants) - Gets all constants
2. [get_defined_functions](http://php.net/get_defined_functions) - Gets all functions
3. [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) - Gets all variables
4. [get_declared_classes](http://php.net/get_declared_classes) - Gets all declared classes

---

```
 I couldn't see any other such predefined superglobal variables in the output
```

**Screw what i said** about this earlier. You are right, doc says

```
phpinfo() is also a valuable debugging tool as it contains all EGPCS (Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server) data.
```

It should be noted, that you find GET, POST and COOKIE in $_REQUEST and not in their array respectivly.

---

If you only want to get the super globals from phpinfo, try following:

```
phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES);
```

Comment: I got all your points except one :  $_COOKIE (which makes sence not to display on phpinfo for security reasons). What are those security reasons? Please explain to me.

Comment: I´ve edited my answer. I was wrong it DOES contain these variables in info. It also contains the cookies in there. I messed up things in my head. Sorry for confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($GLOBALS);
```

alone will give you the long list of all the global variables (both PHP and your own) available to any given part of your app you are in at that moment!

If you put everything into a function and call it when you are looking for something specific, it can make an awesome dev tool.

```
function whats_available(){
echo 'CONSTANTS:';
get_defined_constants();  //- Gets all constants
echo '<br/>';
echo 'FUNCTIONS:';
get_defined_functions();   //- Gets all functions
echo '<br/>';
echo 'VARIABLES:';
get_defined_vars();        //- Gets all variables
echo '<br/>';
echo 'CLASSES:';
get_declared_classes();   //- Gets all classes
echo '<br/>';
echo 'GLOBAL VARIABLES:'; 
print_r($GLOBALS);

}

whats_available();
```